# Create a list of pages excluding children of selected page

Tags: child-pages, exclude, wp-list-pages

I am looking to find a way to create a list of the IDs of children pages from a selected page.

My goal is to use the list of IDs so that I can exclude them from the following function:

```
wp_list_pages(array('exclude' => $###Children_Pages_to_be_excluded###, 'title_li' => ''));
```

I have checked the following question, but I am not sure how to use this function to achieve what I am trying to do.|
[Trying to list out child pages with WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194024/trying-to-list-out-child-pages-with-wp-query?rq=1)

I would appreciate any pointers. Many thanks for your assistance and time.

P.S.

I have managed to solve the problem with the following:

```
//Create an array containing the IDs of pages that are children of page ID XXX"
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_parent' => XXX,
'fields' => 'ids',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);

//Convert the array into a string
$string = implode(', ', $qry->posts);

//Create a list of all pages
wp_list_pages(array('exclude' => $string, 'title_li' => ''));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that any kind of "exclude" or "not_in" type queries can be surprisingly expensive/slow, and don't scale very far. Why are you trying to exclude them? If you provide more context there may be an alternative that doesn't involve `wp_list_pages` or the exclude but still gives you the same result

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Here is what I am trying to do in more detail.

I am creating a dynamic HTML sitemap page containing all the pages from my website.

For this purpose I am using the following function:
wp_list_pages(array('exclude' => '', 'title_li' => ''));

This query works fine and it produces exactly the result I am looking for with one exception.

Comment: What I am trying to do next is to exclude a list of pages, that are all children of a selected page X.

Here is where I'm at currently:

$args = array(
'child_of' => ###ID_of_parent_page_X
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$excluded_pages = get_pages($args);

The final query produces an array of the CONTENT of pages. However, I need an Array of the page IDs, not their content.

Finally, I am trying to use the $excluded_pages variable as an exclude term inside the first function (above).

Hope this explanation is sufficient.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: P.S.

I have managed to create a list of IDs of the child pages using the following query:
$args = array(
       'post_type' => 'page',
       'post_parent' => 11702,
       'fields' => 'ids',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
     );
     $qry = new WP_Query($args);
     var_dump($qry->posts);

I am trying to use it as exclude term here:
wp_list_pages(array('exclude' => '$qry->posts', 'title_li' => ''));

Apparently, I am missing something, as the pages that need to be excluded are still present in the sitemap.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that code inside code blocks? It's unreadable in comments and difficult to follow

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inconvenience! I will try to edit the original post.

Meanwhile, I have managed to solve the problem:
        //Create an array containing the IDs of pages that are children of page ID XXX"
     $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'page',
       'post_parent' => XXX,
       'fields' => 'ids',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
     );
     $qry = new WP_Query($args);
     
     //Convert the array into a string
     $string = implode(', ', $qry->posts);
     
     //Create a list of all pages
     wp_list_pages(array('exclude' => $string, 'title_li' => ''));

Comment: I am sorry, I was unable to edit my own comments. For this reason, I have added the solution to my first post.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create an array containing the IDs of pages that are children of page ID XXX
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_parent' => XXX,
'fields' => 'ids',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);

//Convert the array into a string
$string = implode(', ', $qry->posts);

//Display the list of IDs - for testing purposes.
//var_dump($string);                

//Create a list of all pages excluding the list of child pages
wp_list_pages(array('exclude' => 'XXX,'.$string, 'title_li' => ''));
```